# Display port 1.4 splitters with a GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, gpu, displayport, splitter

I looking for ways to connect more than the 4 displays that are typically supported by one single modern GPU.

[Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0874V968M) is the DP 1.4 splitter in question.
[image]

I would like to use three of such splitters on the 3 DP 1.4 available on a GPU for a total of 9 4k 60Hz displays. All 9 displays should be extendable and work with any OS. Is this realistic or there is there any other way besides plugging in 2 more graphics cards?

Comment: The splitter claims it can extend the displays and can do this for laptops with DP 1.4 going of the Amazon comments. DP 1.4 with DSC supports 8k@60Hz so 3x4k@60Hz with MST should be trivial, no? I was going off this [article](https://www.tripplite.com/products/multi-stream-transport-mst-hub-technology). Please correct me if I'm missing something. Thank you for replying.

Comment: I very much doubt you'll get 9 displays going, even on the highest-end GPUs & most definitely not cross-platform. Read the 'important notes' section for even how limited triple display is.

Comment: @Ramhound given that a GPU with DP 1.4 with DSC is available, 3x3 4k60Hz monitors with say DP 1.2 would be out of the question? I'm asking because DP 1.4 should be backward compatible with DP 1.2 and reading the product reviews is leading me to believe it should work but will it work for all 9 displays, and 3 adapters with 1 GPU?

Comment: @Tetsujin Why should getting 9 displays be unreasonable? Since getting 3 8k Displays running with any current-gen high-end graphics card is very much possible with 3 [DP 1.4 to HDMI 2.1 adapters](https://www.club-3d.com/en/detail/2496/displayport_1.4_to_hdmi_4k120hz_hdr_active_adapter_m-f/). I did and to my understanding, I should be able to drive 3 displays at 4k60Hz. My question is can I do this with all the 3 DP 1.4 ports available or just one? [Linux should also be supporting MST](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247722/intel-skylake-displayport-1-2-mst-daisy-chain-on-linux).

Comment: The RTX 30x0 supports 4 displays. High end Radeons support 6. The current Mac Pro supports more displays than anything else I've seen - up to 12 4k displays, but needs 2 cards to do it. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210228

Comment: @Ramhound "signal conversion to HDMI" wasn't intended for you nor is it my goal to do so. I just need to run 9 4k displays from a graphics card with 3 DP 1.4 ports using splitters.

Comment: @Ramhound That was a typo. I did say more than 4 displays on the first line. I also stated "All 9 displays should be extendable..." in the second to last line in the last paragraph. I apoligize if there was any misunderstanding due to the typing error.